# Use of undeclared identifier 'AppDelegate'

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2

Why do I get this error message with this code?
"Use of undeclared identifier 'AppDelegate'

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is that you haven't declared AppDelegate anywhere.

Answer (score 15):

Did you import the app delegate?

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```